# MS Access Pop-up on table modification

Tags: ms-access

This question might not be really intellectual, but I have an issue with pop-ups in MS Access.

Whenever a modification is about to be brought to a table a pop-up appears telling us that insert, delete, or modification of x rows is about to happen. The thing is i have macros that call tens of queries so when I run the macro I have to click on yes 15 to 20 times before it executes.

Is there a way to reduce the number of pop-ups to 1 or 2? (I still want users to know that modifications are about to happen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `SetWarnings` macro action, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177386%28v=office.12%29.aspx!

You can also do that using VBA, the command is `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`. No system warning will be shown and you can show your own. But don't forget to turn it back on at the end of your macro!

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I couldn't find the setwarning action in the querry builder; I decided to modify itusing the VBA. After visiting the link i understood that i wanted to use the set warning cmd with the warningon argument set to no      DoCmd.SetWarnings (No) but it didn't work. I also tried your vba version didn't work either. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: After a better look-up i could show it in the macro builder (had to select (show all actions) when ilooked a the vba resulting code you were right we should use Docmd.SetWarnings False thx for all